# Using mongoimport to read CSV into nested structure?

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I have a mongo document with a structure like: `{ "foo": { "bar1": "val1", "bar2": "val2"} }`
I'd like to import my data from a csv using `mongoimport --type csv --headerline [...]`

I am not sure how to format the field name in the csv to address the nested structure. For instance:

test.csv:

```
foo.bar1
example
```

returns `{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e9d9d25c5d8708e1f51cdbc"), "foo.bar1" : "example" }`
instead of the desired output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e9d9d25c5d8708e1f51cdbc"), "foo: {"bar1" : "example"} }
```

The field name seems to be interpreted as a string regardless of its value. Things like `foo[bar1]` and `foo: {bar1}` are also used verbatim.

Comment: This may not currently be possible. From [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/4d516486b4ac01c2/de29edd7e2fe94be?lnk=gst&q=mongoimport+nested#de29edd7e2fe94be): No way to do nesting with csv. 
Kind of a weird api. 
Suggestions/patches welcome

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't supported in the current (v2.0) version of mongoimport, but it should be coming soon.  You can check out the JIRA ticket here, scheduled for v2.1:

- [Dotted field names should produce nested objects in mongoimport](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3691)

Until then, if you can translate your CSV data to JSON then you could use `mongoimport --type json` to import the nested data.

**EDIT:**
This feature is released now, and available from `2.8.0-rc0`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column in CSV like `parent_key.array_index.nested_key`

CSV data example

[image: CSV data example]

JSON object image in mongo db after import

[image: JSON object image in mongo db after import]