# Migrate multiple rows of data into single MongoDB document (nested)

Tags: mongodb, csv, data-migration, bson, mongoimport

I want to create a utility which can help in migrating data from Relational DB(*Oracle*) to MongoDB.
Plan is :- 
 **Relation DB -> CSV(*staging area)* -> BSON format** 
 (*conversion to BSON will be based on mappings provided by various use cases*).

 Once BSON is created, Mongo DB's ‘Import’ tool will be used for loading data.

Need suggestions from this expert forum on following problem statement:-
"Most of the relational tables are highly normalized. When I join them to create the data entity, I end up with multiple rows *(E.g. An employee having 3 phone numbers results in 3 rows in CSV file)*. I need to map/convert these three records into one document on BSON *(for embedded document structure)*."

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: What is wrong with [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)? Outside of that, if you are actually asking *"How should I transform all of my relational structure to MongoDB?"*, then that is way **"too-broad"* a question.

Comment: Hi Blakes. I think mongoimport starts with BSON file. I am facing issue in a particular scenario of BSON creation - when multiple records of relational DB need to transform into one document on BSON side,

Comment: Nope. The purpose of `mongoimport` ( link given earlier so you would read it ) is to import "text" content, being either in JSON, CSV or TSV format. You're likely thinking `mongorestore`, which is BSON binary backups.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Blakes and Saleem.I am new to MongoDB and didn't know it can import CSV directly.

Few other threads talking on similar issue:- 

 
[MongoDB - Import CSV into nested document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237912/mongodb-import-csv-into-nested-document) 
[Using mongoimport to read CSV into nested structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809986/using-mongoimport-to-read-csv-into-nested-structure?rq=1) 
[Create nested JSON from CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043229/create-nested-json-from-csv)

Anyone facing the above issue can look at these threads also.